# Map the interface to Class (dynamically) that doesnt implement interface C#

Tags: c#, interface, automapping

This is my first post in Stackoverflow. Thanks to Stackoverflow.

My Question:

I have one interface in class library.

```
namespace TestClient
{
   public interface IMobileStore
   {
        List<string> GetMobileDetails();

        int AddMobile(string mobile);
   }
}
```

And i have class named  MobileLibrary in another class library and implemented IMobileStore interface (While development)

```
namespace MobileLibrary
{
    public class MobileLibrary  : IMobileStore
    {
        List<string> GetMobileDetails()
        {
             return new List<string>();
        }

        int AddMobile(string mobile)
        {
             return 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

And consumed the MobileLibrary library in console application and used.

But now i want to use the IndianMobileLibrary (which is having same structure of MobileLibrary class as below, but it doesn't implement the interface) instead of MobileLibrary

Note: IndianMobileLibrary available in another class library (don't have any control on this library - 3rd party library)

```
namespace IndianMobileLibrary 
{
     public class IndianMobileLibrary  //(doesn't implement the interface)
    {
         List<string> GetMobileDetails()
         {
             return new List<string>();
         }

         int AddMobile(string mobile)
         {
             return 1;
         }
     }
 }
```

Here how to map the IMobileStore dynamically to IndianMobileLibrary (as implementation), and dynamically create object for IMobileStore that implements IndianMobileLibrary class.

As i heard enterprise library dependency injection will help for this. but i dint use the enterprise library still. could you please share the idea for this.

Comment: you have a duck that is not a duck, but you want to make it a duck?

Comment: See here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/597854/Duck-Typing-with-the-Dynamic-Keyword

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to wrap the class which doesn't implement the Interface, in a  simple "proxy" fashion style, just an adapter:

```
public class MyIndianMobileLibrary:IMobileStore
    {
         public MyIndianMobileLibrary(IndianMobileLibrary indian){
          _indianMobileLibrary = indian;
         }
         IndianMobileLibrary _indianMobileLibrary;


         public List<string> GetMobileDetails()
         {
             return indian.GetMobileDetails();
         }

         public int AddMobile(string mobile)
         {
             return indian.AddMobile(mobile);
         }
     }

    public class IndianMobileLibrary  //(doesn't implement the interface)
        {
             public List<string> GetMobileDetails()
             {
                 return new List<string>();
             }

             public int AddMobile(string mobile)
             {
                 return 1;
             }
         }
```

**EDIT**

The solution it's simple but, there is not really necessary, maybe this work:

```
     public class MyIndianMobileLibrary:IndianMobileLibrary,IMobileStore 
    {
         public MyIndianMobileLibrary(){

         }

         public List<string> GetMobileDetails()
         {
             return base.GetMobileDetails();
         }

         public int AddMobile(string mobile)
         {
             return base.AddMobile(mobile);
         }
     }
```

Comment: @lordkain why do you think this is funny? standard proxy/adaptor pattern in practice.

Comment: simple and elegant solution, I was thinking to complex

Comment: Actually beforehand i dont know the class name IndianMobileLibrary itself. Some 3-rd party vendor is developing the IndianMobileLibrary  functionality side by side. Think i have developed one mock project for development while staging only they are providing the original dll. * Before hand i know/agreed only function signatures*

Comment: @user3794983, then I suggest my solution.

Comment: This is overkill, in big projects this doesn't work. You would spend more time writing wrappers than actual code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be interested in the great [impromptu interface](https://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) library (available via nuget). With its help, you can simply do a magic like:

```
var indian = new IndianMobileLibrary();
IMobileStore iface = indian.ActLike<IMobileStore>();
var mobile = iface.AddMobile("test");
```

And you have full intellisense support for `ActLike` returned object of course. Another magic advantage of this is you do not have to know the type of `indian` at all.

Comment: @Konrad, Thanks for your support... I have tried to download impromptu interface Binaries from above link. But i am not getting the dll. Could you please share the (step by step) link from where i can get the proper dll for impromptu interface to add in my project.

Comment: i have installed the impromptu interface Binaries, could you please give idea how to do the above stuff without using indian type as i dont know the type beforehand.

Comment: @user3794983, Just add reference to this dll, add `using ImpromptuInterface;` and call `yourObject`.ActLike<IMobileStore>() to get `IMobileStore` reference.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way around this is to create yourself a proxy to the `IndianMobileLibrary` functionality. You can create a proxy class that does implements `IMobileInterface` but uses the `IndianMobileLibrary` implementation.

uses IndianMobileLibrary;

```
namespace MyIndianMobileLibrary 
{
    public class MyIndianMobileLibraryImpl : IMobileStore
    {
        List<string> GetMobileDetails()
        {
             return new IndianMobileLibrary.GetMobileDetails();
        }

        int AddMobile(string mobile)
        {
             return 1;
        }
}
```

Now you have a compile-able class implementing your logic and can be injected wherever IMobileStore is invoked.